# Indexing multiple tables in BeautfulSoup

Tags: python, html, matplotlib, beautifulsoup, data-science

This page I want to parse - https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/gca/Premier-League-Stats

It has 2 tables, I am trying to get information from the second table, but it keeps displaying the first table every time I run this code.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/gca/Premier-League-Stats').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
stattable = soup.find('table', class_= 'min_width sortable stats_table min_width shade_zero')[1]

print(stattable)
```

min_width sortable stats_table min_width shade_zero is the ID of the 'second' table.

It does not give me an error nor does it return anything. It's null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the second table is dynamically generated, why not combine `selenium`, `BeautifulSoup`, and `pandas` to get what you want?

For example:

```
import time

import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/gca/Premier-League-Stats")
time.sleep(2)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser").find("div", {"id": "div_stats_gca"})
driver.close()

df = pd.read_html(str(soup), skiprows=[0, 1])
df = pd.concat(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

This spits out a `.csv` file that, well, looks like that table you want. :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The HTML you see when you do inspect element are generated using **Javascript**. However, the same classes are not available in the raw html that you get using the script.
I disabled Javascript for this site and I saw that the table is not visible.
You can try something like **Selenium**. There is good information in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python) question.